# word addin disable application events temporarily while vba macro is running

Tags: vba, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I have a Office 2007 Word addin created with Visual studio 2010 with code as shown below:

```
Public Class ThisAddIn
    Private Sub Application_DocumentChange() Handles Application.DocumentChange
        If Application.Documents.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox("document change event.")
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Application_DocumentOpen(Doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document) Handles Application.DocumentOpen
        MsgBox("document open event.")
    End Sub
End Class
```

We have few Word VBA templates (.dotm) and the macros in it may open or close the documents programmatically.

I am looking for a way not to execute these events if macros in VBA template is running.

If we create this addin in VBA, we will create a Global boolean variable and will switch it while the macros are running. Based upon the Global boolean variable value, we will skip these document events. How can I achieve the same in Word addin.

We are looking for .net support hence we are moving to .net.